# Post on Facebook profile/page timeline using Facebook Graph API v3.1 PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As you know that Facebook introduced new Graph API v3.1 on July 26, 2018 that changed many things for developers. One of the questions I have now is how to share/post on Facebook profile/page timeline using Facebook Graph API v3.1 PHP SDK?

> Reminder: Graph API v2.7 will be deprecated on Oct 05, 2018. Please use the [API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/) to understand how this might impact your app. For more details see the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog)

For this I created a new apps with some settings as shown in the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For this purpose, I used the below mentioned code along with [facebook-php-graph-sdk-5.x](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk).

### fbConfig.php

```
<?php
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-graph-sdk-5.x/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId         = 'APP_ID'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret     = 'APP_SECRET'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL   = 'MAIN_PAGE_URL_SAME_AS_IN_APPS_SETTING'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions = array('publish_actions'); //Facebook permission

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
}
?>
```

### index.php

```
<?php
// Include FB configuration file
require_once 'fbConfig.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    //FB post content
    $message = 'Test message from stackoverflow.com website';
    $title = 'Post From Website';
    $link = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';
    $description = 'stackoverflow is simply awesome.';
    $picture = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MybMA.png';

    $attachment = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'name' => $title,
        'link' => $link,
        'description' => $description,
        'picture'=>$picture,
    );

    try{
        // Post to Facebook
        $fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken);

        // Display post submission status
        echo 'The post was published successfully to the Facebook timeline.';
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}else{
    // Get Facebook login URL
    $fbLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

    // Redirect to Facebook login page
    echo '<a href="'.$fbLoginURL.'"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-login-button-png-11.png" /></a>';
}

?>
```

Where as my files level are as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Finally after doing all of the above setting and codes, when I try to run my page then I got LOGIN FACEBOOK BUTTON and after clicking there, I got the below screenshot error.

[image]

What I want is simple post my desired  content without showing any POPUP or dialog so that I can easily use it via my PHP Codes.

I tried to find any working solution over internet but all are now old, nothing is now working with new Facebook Graph API v3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I want is simple post my desired content without showing any POPUP or dialog

That is not possible anymore for user profiles. You have to use Sharing Dialogs instead. `publish_actions` got removed and there is no replacement or workaround.

For Pages, you can use `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` to post to a Page with a Page Token.

Comment: Yep. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/ "The publish_actions permission will be deprecated. This permission granted apps access to publish posts to Facebook as the logged in user. Apps created from today onwards will not have access to this permission... No further apps will be approved to use publish_actions via app review. Developers currently utilizing publish_actions are encouraged to switch to Facebook's Share dialogs for web, iOS and Android."

Comment: (And no, to anticipate the likely follow-up, there's no "workaround" other than the sharing approach. Facebook is **firmly** clamping down here.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing everything and saving my time to search it over internet. Rest I will work with this concept for pages and will forget to do this for Profiles. :)

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Please don't randomly tag people on unrelated questions to draw attention to your new question.

Comment: @ceejayoz The new question is related to this and I was gonna post here in this comment on your reply that there are still way to get these permission for developers but want to know how. Sorry if you got bothered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should post on page feed instead of the personal feed.
As luschn said, you need `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permission to obtain the correct page's access token.

First, you have to develop your app in dev mode, then you need to submit for App Review with those permissions.

This process requires you to upload screencasts with a demo and put the app in a public place so that the Facebook Review team can reach it and test it.

It's a long way to go..